# ZBar SDK no beep sound

Tags: ios, zbar-sdk, beep

I just use ZBar SDK to scan barcode. I want that when the barcode scanned, it can play a beep sound. though the scanning is pretty good. no sound over there. I didn't find any flag in SDK to take control of sound. does anyone meet with this problem? 
I'm new to ZBar. Thank you in advance.
as I know ZXing has beep sound as default.but it can only decode QRCode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ZBar iPhone SDK doesn't automatically play a sound on successful scan.  It's not hard to play one yourself, though:

- Add a sound file you want played to your app, I called mine
  'beep.mp3'.
- Add the AudioToolbox framework to your project.

In header file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Setup (possibly in viewDidLoad):

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef ref = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"beep.mp3", NULL, NULL);
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID);
self.soundID = soundID;
```

Play sound:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.soundID);
```

Comment: hi @smw: i am getting error at my end, ERROR : soundID property not found on object.. Please suggest..